# Login Django not working

Tags: python, django, django-login

I just created a login with Django, but it doesn't want to work. The script should redirect to start.html if the user login correctly. But Django just reload the page writing the username and the passwort in the url.

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic import View

class Index(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "index.html")

    def user_login(request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('^start/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('^err/')
        else:
            print ("Invalid login details")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('^impressum/')
```

urls.py of the project:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from alarm.views import *
from impressum.views import *
from login.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^start/', start.as_view()),
    url(r'^terms/', impressum.as_view()),
    url(r'^err/', error404.as_view())
]
```

Whats wrong with this?

Full code: https://github.com/Croghs/stuport

Thanks for every help and sorry for bad english

Croghs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<form type="post">` to `<form method="post">` in index.html.

Comment: I changed the class to POST and changed the type to method, but now I'm redirected to a blank page ;(

Comment: I think you want "post", not "POST".

Comment: Then he gives an error:       

TypeError at /
post() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: `post`, like `get` or any other method, needs to take self as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Class-based views don't recognise a "user_login" method. It should be called just "post".

Comment: I changed the class to POST and changed the type to method, but now I'm redirected to a blank page ;(